# Buzzing and Humming Sound while recording live Church Service..

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, mixer, microphone-technique

I am trying to record church service but i can hear humming or some kind of buzzing sound in recording how do i fix it.....just for your understanding i have one end coming from mixer out to Pyle-Pro PHA40 4-Channel Stereo Headphone Amplifier and 3.5 jack is been connected to camcorder and other end of jack is been connected to Headphone Amplifier....if you can help me out in this would really appreciated...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A headphone output is not intended as a camcorder input.  A DI box might work as an intermediary.  However, before you go to that expense, it's worth checking out whether the hum disappears if you run the camcorder on battery (namely without connecting it to a power supply: ignore that recording the whole service on battery will likely not work).  If it doesn't, a DI is not likely to help much either.

What kind of input does the camcorder have?  Stereo/mono?  With plugin power?  If it's the latter, switching off the plugin power might help if your camcorder offers a setting for that.

A (passive) DI box will likely survive plugin power, but it biases the transformers which may also lead to distortion and volume loss.  It's easy enough to block (just a suitably large condenser in right polarity in series) but if you can switch it off altogher, you are better off.

Answer (score 0):

Humming could be introduced anywhere in the signal chain, from an unshielded or ungrounded cable or component. It's mains hum - interference from the 50 or 60Hz power circuits in the church.

Diagnosis usually requires swapping out components one by one until you find out when the noise stops.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the line-in on your camcorder, then you should feed it straight from an output on your mixer, rather than going via the headphone amplifier.

The output's of the mixer should be line-level, which is what the line-in on the camcorder would expect.

If your camcorder has a mic-in instead, then you'll need a D.I. box between your mixer output and camcorder mic-in.